# Oracle SQL trigger for automatically set a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am writing a Oracle trigger. This trigger should automatically set the value of the column "productId" to be the oid of the row just inserted.

The trigger I wrote is:

```
create or replace trigger MyProduct_id_trg 
after insert on MyProduct
begin 
   update MyProduct set productId = inserted.oid where oid = inserted.oid;
end;
```

However, this does not work.

Can someone help me with this?

Regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use SQL Server syntax on an Oracle database!  Try this:

```
create or replace trigger MyProduct_id_trg 
before insert on MyProduct
for each row
begin 
   :new.productId := :new.oid;
end;
```

(Note: **before** not after, and with `for each row`.)

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention productId is a varchar2 and oid is int. Do I need to do some type conversion?

Comment: @Kevin - There will be implicit conversion (which will give errors if the product ID is not a perfect number), But is is always recommended you convert it explicitly whenever required. Also, WHY is product ID varchar2 if you will always store a number there?

Comment: Hi. I got the error: ORA-04098: trigger 'MYPRODUCT_ID_TRG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: In SQL Plus you can type "show errors trigger myproduct_id_trg" to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is solved. I just need to use := rather than = for Oracle.