# How to add incrementing key column manually in to existing table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add ID column to existing table. I added new id column. Right now it is contain all null values. I want fill it with incrementing unique IDs.

right now my table is just like following,

```
ID  |  col1 
------------
null   data1
null   data2
null   data3
```

I want to update my table as follows,

```
ID  |  col1 
------------
1    data1
2    data2
3    data3
```

what is the oracle SQL query to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding auto increment identity to existing table in oracle which is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102958/adding-auto-increment-identity-to-existing-table-in-oracle-which-is-not-empty)

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: how to see that?

Comment: Do this right, means with sequence, not rownum or row_number. Look at version 12c identify column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the `ROWNUM` function:**

The Oracle SQL ROWNUM function returns a number that represents the order that a row is selected by Oracle from a table or joined tables. The first row has a ROWNUM of 1, the second has a ROWNUM of 2, and so on.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET ID = ROWNUM;
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5af85/1

Comment: thanx , this is very simple

Comment: Welcome!! If you got your answer please accept and upvote @Nwn

Comment: I'll. had to wait for 7 min.

Comment: This is the best answer.  I don't know why it doesn't have more upvotes.

Comment: I think my reputation is less then others so people think my answer is not good as others. @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `merge`:

```
merge into t using 
      (select t.*, row_number() over (order by rowid) as seqnum
       from t
      ) s
      on (s.rowid = t.rowid)
when matched then update
    set id = seqnum;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc162b/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense order by col1 instead of rowid on condition that data1 is older as data2?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign unique values in the future to that column, generated by a sequence, then create the sequence and update the existing column using that sequence:

```
create sequence my_table_seq;
update my_table
  set id = my_table_seq.nextval;
```

This has the additional benefit, that the sequence is automatically "synchronized" with the highest value in the table.

Comment: Is this solution also valid for releases prior 12c?

Comment: @simpleCode: yes. With 12c I would change the column to an identity column and get rid of the (explicit) sequence