# Addition of values in two columns isn't working in PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

So I am trying to add age with price and store the result on another table with the ID of the person who did this. I am able to set the business rule by making the trigger but when I check my second (END) table, there is nothing there.. Here is my code for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JIM 
    BEFORE INSERT ON END 
    FOR EACH ROW ENABLE
DECLARE
    V_AGE JIM.AGE%TYPE;
    V_PRICE JIM.PRICE%TYPE;
    v_prices NUMBER(20);
BEGIN
    SELECT AGE,PRICE INTO V_AGE,V_PRICE FROM JIM WHERE ID=:NEW.ID;
    v_prices:=V_AGE+V_PRICE;
    INSERT INTO END VALUES(:new.ID,v_prices);
END;
```

However, When I insert values onto the JIM table using the following code:

```
insert into jim values(4,'Sim',45,100);
```

nothing actually gets stored on the END table. i am sort of new to triggers and its so confusing. Please let me know what to do. thanls

Comment: Does nothing get inserted into "END" or is the second column of END a null? (incidentally, I highly recommend renaming END to something that isn't a keyword.  And if END is going to have the same number of rows as JIM, which this trigger is going to facilitate, then you should just add a column to JIM rather than creating a new table).

Comment: Check the syntax. The code you wrote creates a trigger with the name JIM. That is the name of the **trigger**. Then, the trigger is before insert on END. So before you insert in the END table. But you want it to be triggered when you insert in the JIM table!

Comment: And you are trying to insert a value in the same table you created the trigger for. That, IF was possible, would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the `CREATE TABLE` statements, and the exact error messages, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use a keyword `end` as a table name, this causes problem during
  creation of trigger. I've presumed the table's name as `t_end`.
- I think you are confused on which table to define trigger. It seems
  you should define on table `jim` instead of `t_end`.
- I've presumed you have a sequence named `seq_end` to populate the id
  column of the table `t_end`

> So , your *trigger creation statement* will be as follows :

```
create or replace trigger trg_ins_jim before insert on jim for each row
declare
     v_id_end t_end.id%type;
     v_prices t_end.prices%type;
begin
   v_prices := :new.age + :new.price;
   v_id_end :=  seq_end.nextval; insert into t_end values(v_id_end, v_prices);
   /* if you have defined sequence for t_end as default value of id column, you may change the upper row as "insert into t_end(prices) values(v_prices);" and there would be no need for "v_id_end" */
end;
```

and when you issue `insert into jim values(4,'Sim',45,100);` command, you'll also have values inserted into `t_end`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one table, then the `SELECT` and the `INSERT` are redundant.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name 
BEFORE INSERT ON table_name 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.PRICES := :NEW.AGE + :NEW.PRICE;
END;
```

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733148/oracle-sql-trigger-for-automatically-set-a-column-value)

Comment: Well i want to sum it up and put the value in another table so i declared a variable v_prices and made is :=:new.age+:new.price; and then tried to insert it into the END table but got an error